# Is there any memory virtual file API in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, file, memory, virtual

I have a module load a file by its path, 
However I find it is slow.
I want to accelerate it,
Is there any technology in Windows to create a virtual memory file for the module?

Many thanks

Comment: What's slow about your file load? Is it a huge file? Are you doing CPU intensive computations on each line/record? Are you using less than optimal functions to read the file stream? Let's see your code and an idea of the file size/load time. I don't think VM will help you.

Comment: Memory mapped files won't magically make your harddisk work faster. They still go through the same IO system.

Answer (score 4):

I tested [BoxedApp SDK](http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/).

It is awesome, but it is not free :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not *entirely* sure of what you're asking, but if you just want to create a temporary file that will live in RAM (if possible), you can use [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) with [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx#caching_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about memory mapped file, yes there are APIs for that. It's too much to discuss in a little SO answer, and besides it's many many years since I used so I don't even recall the function names. Here's how I found info on that quickly: http://www.google.com/search?q=memory+mapped+file+windows.

However, other simpler means are probably the answer to "I find it is slow".

There can be many different reasons for slowness. Please post some code. Then better answers can be given.

Cheer & hth.,